# Selenium C# - Web element attribute is present but cannot be found?

Tags: c#, selenium

Running into an issue with a function I wrote for a selenuim testcase...  When I run a jquery on a web element ID (#AmountToggle), it displays all the attributes.  I want to verify this one ("lastChild"):

[image]

but when I run this code:

driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#AmountToggle")).GetAttribute("lastChild")

its returning null?!

[image]

Why is this and how can I get the correct value of this attribute?

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML including the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like "lastChild" is a property, not an attribute. Although I cannot assert that for sure with what you have above.

The difference being, an attribute would appear as something in the direct html, such as:

```
<a href="#" id="MyLink">Link</a>
```

Where href and id are attributes. If lastChild doesn't appear in the html like the above examples, it won't be considered an attribute.

First try comparing these two in the javascript console:

```
$("#AmountToggle").attr("lastChild")
$("#AmountToggle").prop("lastChild")
```

The following is a workaround when you have issues with Selenium finding things. This logic will allow you to find things inside of iframes with ease, and also will allow you to use pseudo-selectors to find elements:

```
public static string GetFullyQualifiedXPathToElement(string cssSelector, bool isFullJQuery = false, bool noWarn = false)
        {

            if (cssSelector.Contains("$(") && !isFullJQuery) {

                isFullJQuery = true;

            }
            string finder_method = @"
                        function getPathTo(element) {
                            if(typeof element == 'undefined') return '';
                            if (element.tagName == 'HTML')
                                return '/HTML[1]';
                            if (element===document.body)
                                return '/HTML[1]/BODY[1]';

                            var ix= 0;
                            var siblings = element.parentNode.childNodes;
                            for (var i= 0; i< siblings.length; i++) {
                                var sibling= siblings[i];
                                if (sibling===element)
                                    return getPathTo(element.parentNode)+'/'+element.tagName+'['+(ix+1)+']';
                                if (sibling.nodeType===1 && sibling.tagName===element.tagName)
                                    ix++;
                            }
                        }
            ";
            if(isFullJQuery) {

                cssSelector = cssSelector.TrimEnd(';');

            }
            string executable = isFullJQuery ? string.Format("{0} return getPathTo({1}[0]);", finder_method, cssSelector) : string.Format("{0} return getPathTo($('{1}')[0]);", finder_method, cssSelector.Replace("'", "\""));
            string xpath = string.Empty;
            try {

                xpath = BaseTest.Driver.ExecuteJavaScript<string>(executable);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                if (!noWarn)  {

                    //Warn about failure with custom message.

                }

            }
            if (!noWarn && string.IsNullOrEmpty(xpath)) {

                //Warn about failure with custom message.
                //string.Format("Supplied cssSelector did not point to an element. Selector is \"{0}\".", cssSelector);

            }
            return xpath;

        }
```

This method uses Jquery, which has more extensive search options using CssSelectors (such as pseudo selectors), and finds things 100% of the time given a good search query. This method uses JQuery to find the element, and then generates an explicit XPath to that element in the DOM, returning that XPath. With the explicit XPath, you can then tell Selenium to find the element using XPath.

It looks like the value of last-child is an element itself. If that is true, here is how you might use this in your example:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(GetFullyQualifiedXPathToElement("$(#AmountToggle).prop('lastChild')[0]", true)));
```

Note three things here. The first is that I used "prop" in JQuery. Change that to "attr" if that was the correct call. Also, note the [0] index. This will return the JQuery element value as a regular javascript DOM element, which is what the method above uses. The final thing to note is the cssSelector value passed in. You can pass in just a selector to this method, such as "#SomeElementId > div", or you can pass in full JQuery, such as "$('#SomeElementId > div')".